# Ruby - Working with Mechanize::File response without saving to disk

Tags: ruby, file, orm, zip, mechanize

I'm working on my first ORM project and am using Mechanize.  Here's the situation:

I'm downloading a zip file from my website into a Mechanize::File object. Inside the zip is a file buried three folders deep (folder_1/folder_2/file.txt).  I'd like to pull file.txt out of the zip file and return that instead of the zip file itself.

My first thought was to use zip/zipfilesystem.  I can do this fine if I save the file to the disk first and use Zip::ZipFile.open(src) but can anyone tell me how/if it is possible to send it over straight from the Mechanize::File.body.

My gut says this has to be possible and I'm just missing something basic.  I tried...

```
zipfile = Mechanize::File.body
Zip::ZipFile.open(zipfile)
```

...but from what I can tell Zip::ZipFile is only set up to locate a source from a filesystem.

Any direction would be very appreciated and let me know if there are any questions

Thanks in advance
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what you want to do is not possible with rubyzip. From rubyzip library's [TODO file](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/files/TODO.html):

> - SUggestion: ZipInputStream/ZipOutputStream should accept an IO object in addition to a filename.